# How can I avoid an error: No such environment variable?

Tags: tcl

In my code I am using environment variables, but if it (env.var) doesn't exist, I get the error message NAME_ENV_VAR: no such variable, and my script stops executing.
For example, in the line

```
 myeval $env($File)
```

I receive an error:

```
 can't read "env(NIKE_TECH_DIR)": no such variable
    while executing
"myeval $env($File)"
    (procedure "chooseRelevantFiles" line 39)
    invoked from within
"chooseRelevantFiles $::GlobalVars::reqStage"
(file "/vobs/tavor/src/Scripts/ReproduceBug.tcl" line 575)
```

How can I avoid this error and go on to execute my script?

Answer (score 18):

You could test with `info exists` and use a default if the environment variable is not set, eg.

```
if {[info exists env($File)]} {
    set filename $env($File)
} else {
    set filename /some/default/path
}
myeval $filename
```

Comment: +1 Generally speaking I like to avoid checking if something in the system exists because of race conditions, but in this case it is probably appropriate

Comment: I like the `upvar 0 ::env($stuff) myvar; if {[info exists myvar]} { ...` idiom slightly better.  But it all depends on personal taste.

Comment: @jk.: Catching the error is much slower than avoiding it — Tcl's error handling is _purposefully_ not hyper-fast — but `::env` is a special case that is slow whatever you do (because it's process-global state that can be changed outside of Tcl's control).

Answer (score 6):

[catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/catch.htm) the error then you can do something with it (e.g. log it for later, or use a fall back value) and proceed with your script

e.g.

```
if {[catch {myeval $env($File)} result]} {
    lappend log $result  
}
#other stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

To check for of an array element like global env array, don't use `[info exists $env(VAR)]`.
Instead, you should use:

```
if { [ array names env VAR ] != "" } {
     puts "\nVAR exists and its value is $env(VAR)\n"
}
```

Comment: Why? Why not simply `info exists env(VAR)`? Why the glob matching for the array names?